# Calculating Jordan basis for generalised eigenspaces where the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are high

Tags: linear-algebra

I just finished reading some basics on the Jordan normal form ( mostly just an existence proof for functions where the characteristic polynomial splits).

I determined the JNF for some basic matrices/functions without running into any problems. The cases I ran into where of the sort where the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues where for example 1 and 3.

In this case I know that the desired basis must consist of of one cycle. This gives me some basic equations which I can solve to find possible endpoints for the desired cycle.

Now I am thinking what I should do if I encounter other cases, for example where the algebraic multiplicity is 6 and the geometric mult. is 3. How would I efficiently solve this? Should I first try to find a cycle of length 4? Does such a cycle even necessarily exist?

Comment: What's a cycle?

Comment: The cycle associated with a vector x in the generalised eigenspace of eigenvalue z for the function T is the set of of ((T-z id)^p)(x), for all p so that ((T-z id)^p) (x) is not equal to zero.

Comment: Also called chains, right?  So the chain, or cycle, length is...  the eigenspace dimension, or?

Comment: It depends, if the vector v you choose from the generalised eigenspace of z is an eigenvector of z the cycle length associated with v will be 1. If it is not an actual eigenvector of z the cycle length will be at least 2, furthermore the cycle length of any vector will be at most the dimension of the generalised eigenspace since the vectors in a cycle are linearly independent and all in the generalised eigenspace.